# How not to write full module path in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Lets consider I have a class inside a really long module path:

```
sux = Really::Long::Module::Path::Sucks.new
```

Could I somehow "import" this module in a way that I could just use the class without worrying writing this path every time I use it?

EDIT: I know being in the same module makes things easier. But I can't be in the same module in this case.

Comment: Andrew, were you really complaining about the use of the word 'Sucks' to mean 'not good'? Your tolerance for profanity is unusually low, if so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules are an object in ruby, so you can just make a reference to the module that is shorter.

```
Sux = Really::Long::Module::Path::Sucks
Sux.new
```

Comment: Oops, didn't read your question carefully enough.  Definitely go the `include` route.  I may not delete this question since this is a valid approach in some cases (unless someone objects).

Comment: this sounds actually a more proper way for using just a type from other module. Including a module can be a little more expensive also, so I changed my mind, this is now my chosen answer.

Comment: I would just change that second line, since Sux is now an alias to Sucks class, not an instance of it. Sux.new would do that.

Answer (score 5):

In your class:

```
include Really::Long::Module::Path
```

This basically mixes all of that module's constants/methods into the including class, so you can then use the `Sucks` class directly:

```
sux = Sucks.new
```

Answer (score 3):

```
module A; module B; module C; module D
  class E; end
end; end; end; end

class Sanity
  include A::B::C::D
  puts E.new.object_id
end
```